# How to use jQuery.getJSON() and print it in a bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap, getjson

I'm a student and a real beginner with jQuery and I want to know how to make that `jQuery.getJSON()` read a local file and then print it in a modal (Bootstrap)

here's my local file (fruits.json)

```
{
    Name: “Apple”, 
    Image: “./img/imag_apple.jpg”, 
    Description: “Tasty Apple”, 
    PriceKG: 34, 
    Taxes: 16,
    Number: 28
}
{
    Name: “Orange”, 
    Image: “./img/imag_orange.jpg”, 
    Description: “Tasty Orange”, 
    PriceKG: 34, 
    Taxes: 16,
    Number: 28
}
{
    Name: “Lime”, 
    Image: “./img/imag_lime.jpg”, 
    Description: “Tasty Lime”, 
    PriceKG: 34, 
    Taxes: 16,
    Number: 28
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add grab the data from the response of `getJSON()` and then add that to your modal.

```
jQuery.getJSON(url, function (data) {
  var jsonObj = JSON.stringify(data);
  // add data to modal
});
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/yodadewoci/edit?html,js,console,output)